# How to stop Mule when some condition is met in some class

Tags: xml, mule

The class `phekheij.Tllas` implements `MuleContextNotificationListener` so that it can be run before everything else defined in Mule config:

```
...
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="initializer" class="phekheij.Tllas" />
</spring:beans>

<notifications>
    <notification event="CONTEXT" />
    <notification-listener ref="initializer" />
</notifications>
...
```

What do I have to do so that Mule does not continue running given some condition, for example, when an exception is thrown from inside that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried shutting down Mule during its initialization sequence so I'm unsure what will happen but you could try doing this in phekheij.Tllas:

```
muleContext.stop();
muleContext.dispose();
```

Background threads may keep the JVM running after that so you may end up having to:

```
System.exit(-1);
```

after a while.

Comment: Yeah, without `System.exit(-1)`, it does stop, but Mule output doesn't indicate so. With `System.exit(-1)`, I do see `Stopping app...`.